# Is it true that $\|A\circ \bar{A}\|_2\leq\|AA^{\dagger}\|_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, hadamard-product

Is it true that $\|A\circ \bar{A}\|_2\leq\|AA^{\dagger}\|_2$? Here $\circ$ is the Hardamard product and $\|•\|_2$ is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Is $\|\cdot\|_2$ the induced $2$-norm (spectral norm) or is it the Frobenius norm?

Comment: It is the Frobenius norm. @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that $\|\cdot\|_2$ refers to the spectral norm, i.e. $\|A\|_2 = \sigma_1(A)$.  I am also assuming that $A^\dagger$ is the conjugate-transpose of $A$.

Yes, the inequality that you're looking for holds.  One way to prove this is to note that $A \circ \bar A$ is a principal submatrix of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) $A \otimes \bar A$.

That is, we have 
$$
\|A \otimes \bar A\|_2 = \sigma_1(A \otimes \bar A) = \sigma_1(A) \sigma_1(\bar A) = \sigma_1(A)^2 = \|A\|_2^2
$$
Then, we note that there exists a matrix $P$ such that $P(A \otimes \bar A)P^\dagger = A \circ \bar A$, and that $P$ satisfies $PP^\dagger = I$, which implies that $\|P\| = \|P^\dagger\| = 1$.  It follows that
$$
\|A \circ \bar A\|_2 = \|P(A \otimes \bar A)P^\dagger\|_2 \leq 
\|P\|_2 \cdot \|A \otimes \bar A\|_2 \cdot \|P^\dagger\|_2 = \|A \otimes \bar A\|_2 = \|A\|_2^2
$$
Finally, we note that $\|AA^\dagger\|_2 = \|A\|_2^2$ as well.  So, all together, we have
$$
\|A \circ \bar A\|_2 \leq \|A \otimes \bar A\|_2 = \|A\|_2^2 = \|AA^\dagger\|_2
$$
which means that the desired inequality holds.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also true if it is Frobenius norm?

Comment: @user07001129 yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: $\|AA^{\dagger}\|_F\neq\|A\|_F^2$. So your proof cannot be generalized to the Frobenius norm directly. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: I understand, but the result does hold. I’ll write a proof when I find the time to do so

Comment: I'm actually not so sure that the result holds.  I had a proof in mind, but it seems that the proof doesn't work.